# Is there a shortcut for word boundary in `less`?

Tags: unix

This is the less I am using:

```
less 458 (POSIX regular expressions)
Copyright (C) 1984-2012 Mark Nudelman
```

In Vim it is `\<` and `\>`, in most other regex it is `\b`.

Comment: What's the output of `ldd /usr/bin/less` (presupposing that's the correct path)?

Comment: I don't have ldd (this is OS X)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your version of `less` was built with posix regular expressions, as if:

```
wget http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/less/less-451.tar.gz
tar zxf less-451.tar.gz
cd less-451
./configure --with-regex=posix
make
```

However, apparently the cause of whether `\<` works or not does NOT depend on this:

- In Debian/Linux, `\<` will work fine even if you build with the above commands, with posix regex
- In Mac OS X, I tried all possible values of `--with-regex` except `pcre`, and `\<` doesn't work with any of them. If I build with `pcre`, then `\b` works, instead of `\<`.

To conclude, I don't know how to make it work with `\<`. But you can build yourself with `pcre` and then it should work with `\b`. If you are not a sysadmin, you probably want to use a `--prefix` to install under your home directory, for example `--prefix=$HOME/opt`. After the `make` step, confirm it works with `./less /path/to/some/file`. If looks good, then finish with `make install`.

Comment: On MacOS with `homebrew`: `brew install less --with-pcre` will automatically compile less with PCRE-regular-expressions capabilities.

Answer (score 26):

The character classes `[[:<:]]` and `[[:>:]]` match beginning and end of word, respectively, in system `less` on OS X 10.11.5. I haven't found a way to make the documented short forms `\<`, `\>`, or `\b` work.

(Thanks to [denis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32404674/881629) for the suggestion to check `man 7 re_format`.)

Comment: Ridiculously convoluted solution. Yet again Mac OS behavior is different from  everywhere else.

Answer (score 1):

First see if `man 7 re_format` on your computer has an "Enhanced features"
section which lists `\<` etc.
If it does, change one line in `less-451/pattern.h`:

```
#define REGCOMP_FLAG  REG_ENHANCED  // not REG_EXTENDED
```

Then `./configure --with-regex=posix; make less` will understand `\<` .

This works on Macosx 10.8; on other systems, try following `/usr/include/regex.h` .
(Gnu.org has a round dozen
[Regular-expression-syntaxes](https://www.gnu.org/software/gnulib/manual/html_node/Regular-expression-syntaxes.html)  ?! )

Answer (score 0):

`less` generally uses `vi` syntax, i.e. `\<` and `\>` unless it has been compiled with the `--with-regex=none` configure option or if the regular expression library found at compilation time doesn't provide word boundary search. Your system might also provide a different syntax.

Comment: Answer updated, you should tell what OS your are using as the behavior is platform dependent.

Answer (score 0):

On my macOS v12.6.3 system, the following enables vim-like, `\b` word-boundary-searching:

```
brew install less
echo PAGER='less'
hash -r # in bash, to discover new, homebrew-based less(1) path
```

Also, fyi:

```
$ less --version | head -2
less 608 (PCRE2 regular expressions)
Copyright (C) 1984-2022  Mark Nudelman
$
```

More, related details about my test system:
https://gist.githubusercontent.com/johnnyutahh/0ca86ec252f832cfc512eaf56acecc3c/raw