# How to search git log (using less) for word boundaries

Tags: regex, git, pager

A common workflow for me is to type `git log -p` then search using `/` for text to find changes in the history. I'm on OSX, using the [default pager](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration#idp16732400):

```
$ git config --global core.pager
# no output (meaning default pager, less)
```

When I search, flavors of regexes work, like `a.+b`, however, I can't seem to make **word boundaries** work. I've tried all of the following:

```
<word>
\<word\>
\bword\b
\v<word>
```

The last one is attemping to mimic Vim's `very magic` switch, which I don't know if it exists in `less` but it doesn't error. None of these searches return matches.

**I've tried** turning off color with `git config --global color.ui false` (default value `auto`) but this doesn't seem to have any effect.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22740476/is-there-a-shortcut-for-word-boundary-in-less) makes it sound like `\<` should work? But it doesn't.

My less version:

```
$ less --version
    less 418
    Copyright (C) 1984-2007 Mark Nudelman
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the `less` website FAQ (http://www.greenwoodsoftware.com/less/faq.html) `less` will either use the operating system regular expressions provided by `libc`, or will use its own built-in library if requested during build.

My `less` version is 458. The `\<` and `\>` operators work perfectly.

Your options include :-

1. Check (and possibly update) your `libc` version. (Mine is `libc6-2.19`)
2. Build your own less using more recent libraries or configured to use its internal regular expression handler.

For completeness, Ubuntu 12.04 includes the following versions:

- `less 444`
- `libc6-2.15`

and the regular expressions work as expected.

Comment: I've tried building less from source, but when i use the compiled binary (458) it still appears that \< and \> don't work on OSX. I found this in the FAQ http://www.greenwoodsoftware.com/less/faq.html#searchlt but configuring it with that flag still doesn't make the pattern work :(

Comment: Can I ask, what version of OSX are you running?   I was running Mavericks until yesterday.  Now my less no longer supports \< or \>.... Even installing from macports doesn't fix it.

Comment: I'm running Yosemite 10.10.3